# how to get lowest unit_price for same items in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this :

```
#items: array:12 [
0 => {
  "unit_price": "70"
  "item_name": "item 1"
  "rfq_item_id": 501
}
1 => {
  "unit_price": "100"
  "item_name": "item 2"
  "rfq_item_id": 502
}
2 => {
  "unit_price": "100"
  "item_name": "item 3"
  "rfq_item_id": 503
}
3 => {
  "unit_price": "100"
  "item_name": "test 4"
  "rfq_item_id": 504
}
4 => {
  "unit_price": "110"
  "item_name": "item 1"
  "rfq_item_id": 501
}
5 => {
  "unit_price": "90"
  "item_name": "item 2"
  "rfq_item_id": 502
}
6 => {
  "unit_price": "100"
  "item_name": "item 3"
  "rfq_item_id": 503
}
7 => {
  "unit_price": "110"
  "item_name": "test 4"
  "rfq_item_id": 504
}
8 => {
  "unit_price": "120"
  "item_name": "item 1"
  "rfq_item_id": 501
}
9 => {
  "unit_price": "130"
  "item_name": "item 2"
  "rfq_item_id": 502
}
10 => {
  "unit_price": "80"
  "item_name": "item 3"
  "rfq_item_id": 503
}
11 => {
  "unit_price": "90"
  "item_name": "test 4"
  "rfq_item_id": 504
}
```

]

but i want to get like this

```
  0 => {
  "unit_price": "70"
  "item_name": "item 1"
  "rfq_item_id": 501
}
1 => {
  "unit_price": "90"
  "item_name": "item 2"
  "rfq_item_id": 502
}
2 => {
  "unit_price": "80"
  "item_name": "item 3"
  "rfq_item_id": 503
}
3 => {
  "unit_price": "90"
  "item_name": "test 4"
  "rfq_item_id": 504
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the snippet,

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // checking if result got some data
    if (is_array($result) && count($result) > 0) {
        // fetching item id of all after updating record
        $temp = array_column($result, 'rfq_item_id');
        // check if item id is already in result
        if (in_array($value['rfq_item_id'], $temp)) {
            // find the index of item id in result
            $temp1 = array_search($value['rfq_item_id'], $temp);
            // if result price is greater than new price then replace
            if (isset($result[$temp1]) && $result[$temp1]['unit_price'] > $value['unit_price']) {
                // remove current data as its bigger
                unset($result[$temp1]);
                // add new data
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        } else {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    } else {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
    // reset index   
    $result = array_values($result);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/g5TEM)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [unit_price] => 70
            [item_name] => item 1
            [rfq_item_id] => 501
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [unit_price] => 90
            [item_name] => item 2
            [rfq_item_id] => 502
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [unit_price] => 80
            [item_name] => item 3
            [rfq_item_id] => 503
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [unit_price] => 90
            [item_name] => test 4
            [rfq_item_id] => 504
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want first four elements from array. So use array_slice function.

```
$sliced_array = array_slice($array, 0, 4)
```

Comment: i want to get items with lowest unit_price form same items